# Create a math environment inside itemize

Tags: amsmath, itemize, math-operators

I would like to portray a list of text, were on of these blocks of text needs a centered Summation equation inside of one item of the list. is that possible?

I have very little experience in Latex, so i dont even know were to start ... and sadly i cant even give a example

This is how it should look in theory:

[image: Equation in itemize]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes, I think it is possible. Could you post a small but complete  code of what you tried?

Comment: Atleast provide a screenshot for your requirement (if not able to provide a MWE)...!

Comment: Added a screenshot of how i would like to have it...
@Bernard Sadly i dont know where to start, so i dont have anything to try up to now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item   first item followed with some equation
    \[
\cos x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
    \]
\item   next item next item next item next item next item next item next item next item next item next item next item next item
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Would like to upvote, but dont have enough rep...

Comment: @CleboSevic, you are welcome. i edit my answer and correct typing error ...